# React - Activate sound on render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I manage to activate sound library like

```
import useSound from 

'use-sound';

import boopSfx from '../../sounds/boop.mp3';

const BoopButton = () => {

const [play] = useSound(boopSfx);

return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;

};
```

but I would like to make it go off on render part, like to have some if statement and if its satisfied to play it. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Playing sound on render of button can be achieved using `useEffect` hook in react. You can see the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-dust-u081s?file=/src/App.js).

```
const BoopButton = () => {
  const url = "https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-01a.mp3";

  const [play] = useSound(url);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      play();
    }, 5);
  }, [play]);

  return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;
};
```

The reason I have added the `setTimeOut` is to let the URL load so that sound would play, in your case with link to file, it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'useEffect' hook to play the sound just before the component is rendered.

```
import useSound from 

'use-sound';

import {useEffect} from 'react'

import boopSfx from '../../sounds/boop.mp3';

const BoopButton = () => {

const [play] = useSound(boopSfx);

//keep an empty array to make sure it only executes once
useEffect(()=>play(),[])

return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;

};
```

Comment: Doesnt work. It is still played only when I click on button.

Comment: Works if you add like this   useEffect(()=>play(),[play])

Answer (score 0):

It works this way

```
const [play] = useSound(yourSFX);

useEffect(() => play(), [play])
```

But make sure that your window is in focus. If it's not, click somewhere inside the window and it will start with the play